# Python OpenCV, return an binary array when edge is detected

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, image-processing, edge-detection

By using 'Canny' function in opencv the output argument is numpy array like [0,0,0,0,255] etc. Can i output a binary array like true/false or 1/0 like if detected return 1. Actually matlab do that as default. Please take a look on output section. 
[Find edges in intensity image, Matlab](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/edge.html#buo5g3w-4)

In python code like this:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

img = cv2.imread('messi5.jpg',0)
edges = cv2.Canny(img,100,200) #numpy array. must be binary array (1/0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the output array immediately:

```
 edges_bool = cv2.Canny(img,100,200).astype(bool)
```

Alternatively, you can use later the following function:

```
edges_bool = np.asarray(edges, dtype=bool)
```